# Is It Possible to Reliably Find Editorial Board for the Conference Proceedings?

Tags: citations, conference, editors

I am in the process of submitting thesis corrections and attempting to add sufficient reference information for our school's Thesis Office. They are requesting that I add in the **editors** for Conference Proceedings.

Occasionally, I can find the explicit listing of editors for a conference (I am looking at Control Systems conferences, such as HSCC, ACC, ICRA, etc). With institutional access, I can find the Proceedings on sites such as IEEE Xplore, ScienceDirect, etc., and some of the sites list the editorial boards directly on the site. Others, however, may not list this information, and I try to look at the electronic material available for the proceedings, but cannot find a reliable method to find the editors to add to my reference.

May I ask if anyone has suggestions for reliably finding the Editorial Board? Should I just contact the Program Committees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "editors" for a conference, such as they exist, would typically be the program chairs (if that position exists), or the general chairs (if it does not).  This should be listed on the conference web site or the front matter of its proceedings.

Answer (score 2):

The editors should be the authors of the proceedings. For proceedings published by Springer, e.g., in LNCS they are called "volume editors". ACM lists General and Program chairs of the conference, without calling them "editors". On IEEE sometimes you could see sth like "title page" or "PC Credits" among the first documents in IEEExplore, but I could not find such for ICRA.

So, to summarize, there would be no official "editors" for IEEE conference proceedings like ICRA.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to look for indexing engines( where the conference is indexed). Some databases givs you a direct bibtex or xml file to cite the conference proceedings. Such information should contain the editor/chairs information. [Here](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/aaai/2014) is an example.