# Where can I find the editors of Machine Learning conferences proceedings?

Tags: citations, journals, machine-learning

I am in the process of publishing an article in a journal. The editorial team is asking me to add editors to many references coming from the proceedings of conferences such as AISTATS, MICCAI, ICLR, NeurIPS, etc.

I wrote the references following the pattern illustrated on their website:

```
AuthorA, A., AuthorB, B. & AuthorC, C. Title. In Proc. nth Conference of Something VOLUME, startpage–endpage (Publisher, YEAR)
```

How can I find the relevant editors they ask for ? Is there a correspondence between General Chairs and editors ? Does it even make sense for proceedings ? What can I answer the editorial team ?

Comment: I realize this is a non-answer, but I just Googled `AISTATS` and [found the editors of the proceedings pretty quickly](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v151/). YMMV for the other ones.  It does seem odd to request both the authors of the papers AND the editors of the proceedings, though the [IEEE reference style guide](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) does have a variant that includes them. Look for "Conference Proceedings With Editors".

Comment: @PeterK thank for your answer ! Just found this as well which might answer the question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31716/is-it-possible-to-reliably-find-editorial-board-for-the-conference-proceedings